# building custom and simple regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build simple regex with js.

the rules for the regex are:

Length: 6-32 characters.

alphanumric characters.

at least 1 letter and 1 digit.

special characters: not allowed.

whitespace: not allowed.

i came up with this: `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/`

but is not working well.

Comment: Not working well could mean anything. In this case, at least, you provided the code, and it's clearly wrong. Why the lookaheads?

Comment: Your re doesnt really match what your after?, which would be; `/^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,32}$/`

Comment: i have updated my question. added "at least 1 letter and 1 digit"

Comment: Try out this tool for learning regex http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use negative lookaheads:

```
/(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,32})$/
```

Comment: Could you care to leave a comment as to why this was downvoted?

Comment: Not sure why anyone would downvote this. Lookaheads are commonly used and are the correct expression for this purpose. There are lots of answers like this one that work like a charm. +1.

Answer (score 1):

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,32}$/` does the required job.

Comment: i have updated my question. added "at least 1 letter and 1 digit"

Comment: what about "at least 1 letter and 1 digit."

Comment: That requirement came in later as you can see from the OP's comment above yours.

Comment: I hear you! removing my downvote. Update: Still cannot remove my downvote even after editing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Length: 6 - 32 characters:

```
/^.{6,32}$/
```

Only alpha-numeric:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,32}$/
```

Answer (score -1):

Regexp is **not** a programming language. Don't try to stuff all logic in it.

You have 3 conditions - use 3 regexps!

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,32}$/.test(string) && /[a-zA-Z]/.test(string) && /[0-9]/.test(string)
```

Comment: This is a common requirement for passwords and achievable by lookaheads. Its not like he is trying to parse html.

Comment: @Kash, it also "achieves" write-only and easily breakable code.

Comment: can you give an example? I understand regexes can get "write-only" but how is it easily breakable?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - Just because you may be uncomfortable with non-trivial regex does not mean everyone else is too. I consider Kash's regex to be trivial and correct. The only reason to divide up the tests would be to provide a unique error message for each failure type (which your answer does not provide. Your solution is longer, more complex and slower. -1.

Comment: Also, regex _is_ a programming language!

Comment: @Kash, add to requirements: allow two more symbols (say `_` and `$`), while leaving 1 number and 1 alpha constraint intact. Good luck keeping it readable!

Comment: @ridgerunner, it is longer only thanks to JavaScript fluff around it. It'd be shorter in Perl. More complex? Is that an elaborate joke? Show two examples to someone who started doing rx last week and ask to explain what's going on there. As for speed: yes, mismatch detection happens 3 times faster, but match is pretty much the same. With slowest being 3m matches per second on my old PC. http://jsperf.com/regexp-combining-with-logic-vs-lookaheads